# Can php and asp.net work with the same database?

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, sql, database

I work with php but there is a program written in .net that I would like to pull data from. The company is willing to partner with me and allow me to pull the data... but I don't know a single thing about .net so I don't know if I will be able to pull it with php or if I will have to hire someone fluent in .net. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I assume the data your referring to is in a database somewhere? What kind of database?

Comment: if this app listens to a port and accepts commands, then php socks could help =)

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain the .net application talks to [SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php). It is trivial to connect. No matter what database, it very likely there are at least ODBC drivers. So in theory you should be able to talk to any db.

[Here is a list of databases](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php) supported by php natively.

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports many databases. See this list: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php